# Spring security: endpoint unauthenticated is trying to be authenticated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Here my `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource = serverWebExchange -> {
            final var cc = new CorsConfiguration();
            cc.addAllowedOriginPattern(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);

            return cc;
        };

        Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.jwt();

        return http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(configurationSource).and()
            .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers(
                    "/keycloak",
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
              )
              .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
            .build();
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm allowing `/keycloak` endpoint in order to call it unauthenticated.

However, when I'm calling this endpoint I'm reaching this response:

```
$ http -v GET $API_SERVER/keycloak clientId==$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID clientSecret==$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET

GET /keycloak?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=Lsx8nSOxKfeSYPBIDgDMjMtD2KTPvma5 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: HTTPie/3.2.1
Host: api-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es

HTTP/1.1 401 

vary: Origin
vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=AD9C22513404F342B07B828878BDBDD1; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: 81d19e38397896573410aee2d8d4fe76=43a159f8dcfa8179b6ba9fae52676052; path=/; HttpOnly
www-authenticate: Bearer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
content-length: 0
date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 14:05:21 GMT
```

On my service I'm getting this trace:

```
2023-04-25 14:10:08.599  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                 :

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/keycloak?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=Lsx8nSOxKfeSYPBIDgDMjMtD2KTPvma5':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@56215287

servletPath:/keycloak
pathInfo:null
headers:
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: */*
user-agent: HTTPie/3.2.1
host: api-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es
x-forwarded-host: api-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es
x-forwarded-port: 80
x-forwarded-proto: http
forwarded: for=10.49.88.118;host=api-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es;proto=http


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2023-04-25 14:10:08.600 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /keycloak?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=Lsx8nSOxKfeSYPBIDgDMjMtD2KTPvma5
2023-04-25 14:10:08.600 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-25 14:10:08.602  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                 :

************************************************************

New HTTP session created: 34CAE9608DEE0A209767B7F95B3C1071

Call stack:

    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter$DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAuthenticationException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


************************************************************


2023-04-25 14:10:08.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://api-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/keycloak?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=Lsx8nSOxKfeSYPBIDgDMjMtD2KTPvma5 to session
2023-04-25 14:10:08.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-25 14:10:08.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Why spring security is trying to authenticate this request?

My controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TokenController {

    private final OAuth2TokenProvider oauth2TokenProvider;

    @GetMapping("/keycloak")
    public String getToken(@RequestParam String clientId, @RequestParam String clientSecret) {
        return this.oauth2TokenProvider.getToken(clientId, clientSecret);
    }

}
```

Comment: *Why spring security is trying to authenticate this request?* It is not authenticate `/keycloak`, it is authenticate `/token` as your curl log shows: `GET /token?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=Lsx8nSOxKfeSYPBIDgDMjMtD2KTPvma5` To access the token endpoint you have to send basic auth credentials of your client.

Comment: Sorry, it was a miswritting (I tested a lot od requests and I copied the wrong one). I don't quite figure out why I need to provide basic auth on `/keycloak`? I mean, `httpBasic` is disabled...